# jquery not waiting the confirm message, it is running all functions

Tags: jquery

I have a multi select Gridview , If a user for example selected 3 rows in the grid : name 1, name2, name3. i should show the user a popup confirm message, are you sure ?.

the problem in jquery , it doesnt wait the confirm message, it calls all the functions. **what I want is the know the result of the message first then call the functions**

Edited:

```
function dosomething() 
{

    var $current = $("#confirm"); 
    var gridId = $("#Grid_Id");
    var confirmedArr = new Array;
    confirmedArr = gridId.jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');
    var n=0;
    var i = 0;


    var arrayLength = confirmedArr.length;
    var user_id;    



        alert(arrayLength);
        if($current.is(":checked"))
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) 
            {       
                var confirmMsg = "set off USER "+ confirmedArr[i];
                _showConfirmMsg(confirmMsg, "Are you sure ?", function(confirmChoice, theArgs)
                {
                    user_id = confirmedArr[i];
                    console.log(user_id);
                    usrar=user_id;
                    if (i>0)
                    {
                    usrar=  user_id +usrar;
                    }
                if (arrayLength==i)
                    {
                    confirmedme(usrar);
                    }
                });
            }

        }
        else
        {
        confirmedUserArr = gridId.jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');
         confirmedme(confirmedArr);
        }

    }


function confirmedme(confirmedArr)
{
alert("confirm me");
}
```

Comment: why the downvote ? it is not clear

Comment: 1. Format your code properly. 2. Fix syntax errors. 3. What is `_showConfirmMsg`? 4. If `_showConfirmMsg` is async (that is why it has callback argument) why would your code wait for it?

Comment: Probably because your code is not formatted correctly. You should edit a bit... Check for correct indentation. By the way, your first function misses a `}` at the end. (Maybe a typo).

Comment: my code is really long ,this is a just simple , to show you my problem. ill try to edit it @YuryTarabanko

Comment: You mean this is just a sample. Plz, show the real code part that is not working. Don't try to write it on the fly approximately... Because what is actually posted contains more syntax error than lines.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette okay ill show my real code , i need some minutes

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette can you check my edit please , this is working script, my problem that
 function confirmedme() is being executed even if my confirm checking didnt finish, for example if i click 3 rows, it will ask if i am sure for the first row, i click yes then the function confirmedme me will be called. but i dont want to be called i want to confirm the rest 2 rows then to call the function

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is try calling your function inside the callback depending on the choice, of course, something like this.

```
_showConfirmMsg(confirmMsg, "Are you sure ?", function(confirmChoice, theArgs) {
     user_id = confirmedArr[i];
     i++;
     // Call your function here.
     if (confirmChoice == something) {
        yourFunction();
     }
}
```

UPDATED:

Try moving this block out of your for loop.

```
if (arrayLength==i)
{
    confirmedme(usrar);
}
```

Something like this:

```
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {       
    var confirmMsg = "set off USER "+ confirmedArr[i];
    _showConfirmMsg(confirmMsg, "Are you sure ?", function(confirmChoice, theArgs) {
        // Blah blah
        count ++;
     });
}

if (arrayLength==count)
{
    confirmedme(usrar); // Not sure how you use the usrar but make sure you declare this variable before the loop.
}
```

Comment: what should I add for something ?

Comment: Well, it's just my assumption that you need to check for the confirm choice value before calling the function. If it's not the case, just remove the if() condition and put your function call there.

Comment: ill show you my update code , might you can help me more

Comment: can you check my edit please , this is working script, my problem that
 function confirmedme() is being executed even if my confirm checking didnt work, for example if i click 3 rows, it will ask if i am sure for the first row, i click yes then the function confirmedme me will be called. but i dont want to be called i want to confirm the rest 2 rows then to call the function

Comment: okay ill explain what happend . i add alert(count) before this 
`if (arrayLength==count)` on the first showconfirm the alert was executed. what is the happening that its executing everything and its waiting the confirm message

Comment: Maybe knowing what you do with _showConfirmMsg would make it easier for debugging.

Comment: its a function developed by the company , i cannot show it here. however it shows a message if i want to do something

Answer (score 0):

try changing:

```
_showConfirmMsg(confirmMsg, ""Are you sure ?", function(confirmChoice, theArgs)
```

to:

```
_showConfirmMsg(confirmMsg, "Are you sure ?", function(confirmChoice, theArgs)
```